# The latest com.google.android.gms for google play services revision 6

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, google-play-services

I was running my Android Google Maps application using Google Play services revision 5 and it worked well...

I updated my Google Play services from revision 5 to revision 6 and now it won't run and produces this warning:

```
Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 3025110
```

Any idea where I can find the latest com.google.android.gms.apk file to meet the requirement?

Comment: are you running this on a real device?

Comment: nope! im running it on an emulator...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did the same thing :(

Here is how to solve it by rolling back: Uninstall Google Play Services 6 then download Google Play Services 5 here http://venomvendor.blogspot.com/2012/03/android-sdk-extras-by-google-inc.html and put it under /extras/google/google-play-services

FYI I also need to install

> adb install -r com.android.vending-1.apk
>
> adb install -r com.google.android.gms-3025110-v3.0.25\ (583950-10).apk

for my Google Maps app to work on my emulator...

Rebuild your apk using Google Play Services 5.

Comment: Hello... I need 3027100 version... Where did you find com.google.android.gms-3025110-v3.0.25\ (583950-10).apk ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this on a real device then you would need to update the `Google play services` via the `Google play store`. This actually should be done automatically but you can speed up the process by doing it manually through the store.

If you are running this on a "modified" AVD(were you installed the `Google play services` manually).
then you would need to install a new set of files.

Comment: any idea where i can find these new set of files?

Comment: there is some kind of way to produce them from a real device. but I have no idea how it's done.

Comment: If you need to update via the Google Play store you can visit this on device: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en

Answer (score 0):

you can use adb pull, you can also use "Terminal" of any type and the "cat" command, and sd memory.

```
cd /data/app #or wherever..
cat com.google.android.gms-1.apk > /mnt/sdcard/GoogleSpywareBackupFile.apk
```

You can't merely use "cat" to install it, however. But you probably already know that, given how the question was asked.

Comment: Support for emulator is in progress. Read comments #36 and #37: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4627#c36