# getMap() returning null

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

My getMap() method is returning null.  Why is this method returning null?  I looked on the Android Developers documentation to make sure I'm using this method correctly.  Here a the line of code that I'm using to get the map:

```
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myMapView)).getMap();
```

Here is my Java code:

```
private ProjectionProxy proxy = new ProjectionProxy();

private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle load) { 
    super.onCreate(load);

    setContentView(R.layout.fragment_ride_tracking);

    mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myMapView)).getMap();

    Log.e("RideTracking", "Google Map VALUE:"+mMap);

    if (mMap != null) { 
        proxy.setProjection(mMap.getProjection());
    }
```

Here is my XML code for that particular piece of code:

```
   <fragment 
    android:id="@+id/myMapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

Here is the logcat output:

```
05-09 12:49:34.282: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5928): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
05-09 12:49:34.282: E/RideTracking(5928): Google Map VALUE:null
05-09 12:49:34.302: E/OGT.GPSLoggerServiceManager(5928): No GPSLoggerRemote service connected to this manager
05-09 12:49:34.322: W/dalvikvm(5928): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/android/gpstracker/viewer/FixedMyLocationOverlay; (2174)
05-09 12:49:34.322: W/dalvikvm(5928): Link of class 'Lcom/android/gpstracker/viewer/FixedMyLocationOverlay;' failed
05-09 12:49:34.322: W/dalvikvm(5928): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/android/gpstracker/viewer/FixedMyLocationOverlay; (2174)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you testing on the emulator? I haven't tried in a while but the map services used to not be available on the emulator.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that.  No luck.

Comment: Sorry changed my comment. I meant emulator not debugger.

Comment: Possible help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039788/the-latest-com-google-android-gms-for-google-play-services-revision-6

Comment: The Logcat output is what I get when I run it in the emulator.

Comment: @user268397 run your app on real device and check

Comment: I tried that and it crashes!

Answer (score 0):

Try Changing it like that

```
GoogleMap googleMap;

MapFragment fm = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myMapView);


googleMap = fm.getMap();
```

If you are running it in Emulator you need to install two apk files [(Read this Post)](http://mzubair.com/android-how-to-make-the-emulator-run-maps-v2/)

If you have tweaked the Emulator and installed the two files already then you have to change the Google_Play_services_lib to version 4 [(download it here)](http://venomvendor.blogspot.co.il/2012/03/android-sdk-extras-by-google-inc.html)

Just replace the new Google_Play_services_lib with the old **version#4** in eclipse and reference this to the project.

Comment: I have version 6 of Google Play Services library.  Is that good enough?

Comment: change it to rev 4 just to test with the emulator

Comment: If you want to run maps on Emulator you have to install these two APK file via adb 'adb install com.android.vending.apk 

             adb install  com.google.android.gms.apk'

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the line

```
05-09 12:49:34.282: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5928): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110
```

tells us why the map isn't instantiated.

You need to have a current version of Google Play services on your device or else you get this:
[image: This app won't run without Google Play Services]
and `getMap()` will return `null`.