# Null pointer exception on MapView

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I cannot seem to find a solution to the following issue. Im getting a `null pointer exception` on the following MapView i'm trying to use within an Activity.

Java

```
public class ActivityMAIN extends FragmentActivity implements LocationListener {

private GoogleMap mMap;
```

...

```
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myMapView)).getMap();
       //LOGCAT shows Null at above statement only

LatLng sydney = new LatLng(-33.867, 151.206);

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(sydney, 13));

    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .title("Sydney")
            .snippet("The most populous city in Australia.")
            .position(sydney));
```

XML

```
<fragment 
  android:id="@+id/myMapView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"/>
```

LogCat

```
02-02 12:42:51.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4003): Process: com.testing.googlemaps, PID: 4003
02-02 12:42:51.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4003): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testing.googlemaps/com.testing.googlemaps.ActivityMAIN}: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-02 12:42:51.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
02-02 12:42:51.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
02-02 12:42:51.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
02-02 12:42:51.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4003):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
02-02 12:42:51.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4003):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
02-02 12:42:51.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4003):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
02-02 12:42:51.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
02-02 12:42:51.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4003):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-02 12:42:51.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4003):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-02 12:42:51.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4003):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
02-02 12:42:51.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4003):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
02-02 12:42:51.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4003):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native     Method)
02-02 12:42:51.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4003): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-02 12:42:51.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4003):     at com.testing.googlemaps.ActivityMAIN.onCreate(ActivityMAIN.java:150)
02-02 12:42:51.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4003):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
02-02 12:42:51.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4003):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
02-02 12:42:51.356: E/AndroidRuntime(4003):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
```

Comment: Have you called `setContentView()` first to load up that layout? Why are you using `MapFragment`, instead of `SupportMapFragment`, given that you are using `FragmentActivity`?

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be the time when you call your fragment.getMap() method, you are trying to get the map on your activity creation, at this time the fragment isn't showed, so the fragment exist but not the GoogleMap element, try to do that on the onResume() method of your activity or make sure you have set the content of your activity using setContentView(...)

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks Fine but in xml you have to change this Line

**android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment"**

to

**android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"**

Answer (score 0):

```
mMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myMapView)).getMap();
   //LOGCAT shows Null at above statement only
```

Did you confirm that `((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.myMapView))` is not null? On this line is that possible that it can be null?

Some discussion over here might help about google services: [getMap() returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468276/getmap-returning-null)