# downgrading google play services from 6 to 5

Tags: android, google-maps, google-play-services

[the image of SDK](http://img195.imageshack.us/img195/2198/downgradeb.jpg)
i want to downgrade the version of my google play services from rev version 6 to rev version 5.
i need this to run maps on emulator but i cant figure out on how to do it.
[i have found a kind of solution here][2]

[2]: [The latest com.google.android.gms for google play services revision 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039788/the-latest-com-google-android-gms-for-google-play-services-revision-6) but i can't figure out how to actually downgrade it.
on this version i am getting an error

> Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3027100 but found 2012110

if anybody know on how to do it then please share or if anyone can provide the new apk files to be installed on the device to get it to work with the maps.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can download an older revision from here:

http://venomvendor.blogspot.co.il/2012/03/android-sdk-extras-by-google-inc.html

Then remove the newer version from workspace, and add the desired one.

Once you did that you can refrence it with your project and check again.

You can read this blog post I wrote on this matter as well:

[Google Maps API V2 in Emulator](https://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=527)

Comment: yes, you just told what i want to do but that is not the problem. i am stuck at actual downgrading of the revesion version. i have downloaded the revision version from the link you gave. i then delete the google play services package from the sdk. then i placed the files i downloaded to the directory of android sdk. then i started the sdk again and it showed me this http://img802.imageshack.us/img802/6684/downgrade2.jpg this is where i am stuck. i just cant figure out how to actually make the google play services to go down to revision 5 or 4. if you can eaborate this step a little more.thanks

Comment: there is no need to put the download folder into the sdk folder. what you need to do is replace the newer version you have added as a project in eclipse with this version. and reference it instead of the newer one from your map project.

Comment: you are a life saver dude. thank you so much. the activity is working now but it is showing white scree. i think it is due to the key, i will fix it...anyways thanks for your help