# Android Google Map error when I've open

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, adb, ubuntu-14.04

I've problem with android google map, more exactly when I tried to open the map on my application I've recive this error:

```
8-06 02:51:56.627  15513-15513/com.cetabo.trackingpoint E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.cetabo.trackingpoint, PID: 15513
    android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=market://details?id=com.google.android.gms flg=0x80000 pkg=com.android.vending }
            at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1781)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1501)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3745)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3706)
            at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:817)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4016)
            at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3984)
            at com.google.android.gms.dynamic.zza$5.onClick(Unknown Source)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19866)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

To solve that problem I've tried 2 method but no one don't works for me :(

1. First I've try to use that commands in Ubuntu 14.04:

   adb install com.google.android.apps.maps-1.apk
   adb install com.google.android.gms-2.apk

But I can't install this because I've recive that error message 
can't find 'adb install com.google.android.apps.maps-1.apk' to install
can't find 'adb install com.google.android.gms-2.apk' to install

2. The second method I've tried was to install all the new update from SDK Manager, but again... don't works :(

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qJ6x2.png

So pleas if anyone know how can I make this map works, pleas help me.

Comment: Google map is not loaded in your activity ???

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16039788/the-latest-com-google-android-gms-for-google-play-services-revision-6

Comment: ummm... sounds like you do not have Google Play Service installed on your phone and your phone do not have a Google Play Store, and so when the system trying to redirect your user to download the Google Play Services, it crashes. If you are testing it on the emulator, then try to test it on the one with the "Google Inc." keyword, which include Google Play services.